# How to find the point on the root locus for which the damping is equal to 0.7 in Octave?

Tags: octave

I don't have MatLab installed on my computer, so I am trying to do a laboratory exercise in Control Engineering in Octave. In that laboratory exercise, I am supposed to find the gain at the point on the root locus where damping is equal to 0.7. Octave does support the `rlocus` command, however, in the window where the root locus is opened, in the "Tools" menu, there is no "Data Tips" option (that the instructions advise us to use). So, how can I find the point on the root locus where the damping is equal to 0.7 in Octave? Are you supposed to somehow get an array of the coordinates of all the points on the root locus and find the one for which the cos(atan(y/x)) (I think that's how the formula goes, but I am not sure) is the closest to 0.7, or?

Comment: Have you tried using `rlocusx`? "In contrast to rlocus(), mouse clicks on the root locus display the related gain and all other poles resulting from this gain together with damping and frequency of conjugate complex pole pairs."

Comment: @NickJ Never heard of it.

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/function/rlocusx.html